# Xcode 15 - preview screen shift problem in UIKit

Tags: swift, uikit, xcode15

I want to edit a view of my project using a preview, but I'm experiencing shifting issues on the preview screen (using iPhone 14 Pro display). I can't scale properly, resulting in white gaps on the left and top edges.

Here is my view class
Thank you all for answers.

```
import UIKit
import SnapKit
class MRPFavoritesBlankView : UIView {
    lazy var labelFavorites : UILabel = {
        let label = UILabel()
        label.text = "Favorites "
        label.font = UIFont.tommySoftBold(size: 30)
        label.textColor = .white
        label.textAlignment = .left
        return label
    }()
    lazy var imageViewBlank : UIImageView = {
        let imageView = UIImageView()
        imageView.image = UIImage(named: "image_blank_view")
        imageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
        return imageView
    }()
    lazy var labelNoFavorite : UILabel = {
        let label = UILabel()
        label.text = "You don't have any favorite songs"
        label.font = UIFont.tommySoftThin(size: 18)
        label.textColor = .white
        return label
    }()
    lazy var buttonDiscover : UIButton = {
        let button = UIButton()
        button.setTitle("Let's discover", for: .normal)
        button.titleLabel?.font = UIFont.tommySoftMedium(size: 18)
        button.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(named: "button_lets_discover"), for: .normal)
        button.setTitleColor(.black, for: .normal)
        return button
    }()
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        setUpView()
    }
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
    private func setUpView(){
        addBackgroundImageView(to: self, imageName: "image_background")
        addSubviews(labelFavorites,imageViewBlank,labelNoFavorite,buttonDiscover)
        labelFavorites.snp.makeConstraints { make in
            make.top.equalToSuperview().offset(30)
            make.left.equalToSuperview().offset(20)
            make.width.equalToSuperview()
            make.height.equalTo(30)
        }
        
        imageViewBlank.backgroundColor = .red
        imageViewBlank.snp.makeConstraints { make in
            make.width.equalTo(350)
            make.height.equalTo(350)
            make.top.equalTo(labelFavorites.snp.bottom).offset(40)
        }
        labelNoFavorite.snp.makeConstraints { make in
                make.top.equalTo(imageViewBlank.snp.bottom).offset(30)
                make.left.equalToSuperview().offset(20)
                make.width.equalToSuperview()
                make.height.equalTo(30)
                make.centerX.equalToSuperview()
        }
        buttonDiscover.snp.makeConstraints { make in
            make.width.equalTo(0.8 * screenWidth)
            make.height.equalTo(0.07 * screenHeight)
            make.centerX.equalToSuperview()
            make.top.equalTo(labelNoFavorite.snp.bottom).offset(15)
        }
    }
}

#Preview{
 MRPFavoritesBlankView()
}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Os6Ov.png)`import Foundation